# Firebase Cloud function via https.onCall

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Am trying to call a firebase cloud function via https.onCall from either a web browser, or by using a curl command. I get the following response with curl:

```json
{"error":{"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","message":"Bad Request"}}
```

When I try via browser (and authenticated on firebase), I get an error: domain ... "not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header",

which probably is more to do with http cross domain requests, not firebase. I have tried to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to '*', but to no avail.

Since I am trying to get the https.onCall to work, I have used a super simple method for the server function:

```js
        exports.testClientCall = functions.https.onCall((req, res) => { 
         var jsonObj = {"Founder": "Apple"};
        var json = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
      response.send(json);
        });
```

The client function in web browser is:

```js
    function getDataFromFirebaseFunction() {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://us-central1-<myproject>.cloudfunctions.net/testClientCall";
    var params = {"hello":"friend" };
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    
    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    http.setRequestHeader("X-MyHeader", "123");
    http.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    http.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
     
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
    }
```

Struggling all round to execute a firebase cloud function via a client. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you not using the client SDK, which does all the hard work of managing the protocol between client and server?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Will give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved. However, I needed to add a "defer" to firebase functions src as follows: <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>

Comment: @RowanGontier may I ask you to post your solution as an answer?

Comment: Done- solution in answer.

Answer (score -1):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
          <!-- update the version number as needed -->
          <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.12.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
          <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
          <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.12.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
          <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.12.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
          <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.12.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
          <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.12.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
          <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
        
          <!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
          <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>   
        
          <script>
          function executeHttpsCallableUsingClientSDK() {
    //Send a name to firebase cloud function, and get response data
    
            var testClientCall = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('testClientCall');
            testClientCall ({name: "Steve Jobs"}).then(function(result) {
          // Read result of the Cloud Function.
              console.log("Client done with firebase function request, with result:");
              console.log(result);
        });
          }
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        
        </body>
        </html>
```